# Access json data outside of $.getJSON()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = getParmsVals()["search"];
    $.getJSON('/api/search/GetQuestionByKey/' + value, function (jsonData) {
        $(jsonData).each(function (i, item) {
            var name = getAuthorName(item.userId);
        });
    });
});

function getAuthorName(userId) {
    var fullname = "default";
    $.getJSON('/api/search/GetUserById/' + userId, function (jsonData) {
        fullname = jsonData.firstname + " " + jsonData.lastname;
    });
    return fullname;
}
```

I'm trying to access the fullname variable by calling the getAuthorName method but I couldn't get the correct value. It's always giving me the value "default".

Comment: are you receiving any console errors?

Comment: Could you show us your jsonData output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. You are returning `fullname` before `$.getJSON` has received a response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wouldn't `return` from an async method, as you can see, it doesn't work! What you need is a callback function, consider:

```
function getAuthorName(userId, callback) {
    var fullname = "default";
    $.getJSON('/api/search/GetUserById/' + userId, function (jsonData) {
        fullname = jsonData.firstname + " " + jsonData.lastname;
        callback(fullname);
    });
}
```

Notice how we pass in `callback` and then call it at the end of your get call? Now call this method like so:

```
getAuthorName(userID, function(name) {
    console.log(name);
});
```

And now you have access to `fullname` in that callback function!

Comment: Couldn't he set `async: false` as well? I like your answer better either way though.

Comment: @MagicMan -- Setting async to false is never a good idea, if that service is down, that call hangs, locking up the user. Users hate that!

Comment: @MagicMan you should never set async:false there is always a better way to do it.

Comment: @b1tsh1ft unless your'e in onbeforeunload, or an anchor tag click that you don't want to prevent, or a form submit that you don't want to prevent. there are plenty of use cases where it's not a bad idea to use it, this just isn't one of them.

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for your answer.. So if I have to use $.getJSON() method more than once is there a better way to call it? Other than calling it in different functions??

Comment: you can do:

$.ajax({
   async: false
});

// do the $.getJSON normally

$.ajax({
   async: true
});

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by @tymeJV it is an easy solve to the problem

I just wanted to point out that solving the big picture of having easily accessible data inside Javascript is a great reason why data-centric JS frameworks exist

http://knockoutjs.com/
http://backbonejs.org/
http://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can also put your variable on the object and use `.bind()`, like so:

```
this.fullname = "default";

$.getJSON('/api/search/GetUserById/' + userId, function (jsonData) {
   this.fullname = jsonData.firstname + " " + jsonData.lastname;
}.bind(this));
```